# Timer alert - FIX

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, function, timer, alert

I have a timer alert:

```
private var cheat:Timer;

private function init():void {
    cheat = new Timer(2000, 1);
    cheat.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, cheatProtection);
}

private function showAlert():void {
    cheat.reset();
    cheat.start();
}
private function alrt_close(evt:CloseEvent):void {
    cheat.stop();
}

private function cheatProtection(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    Alert.show("Text", "Label", Alert.OK, this, alrt_close);
}
```

So what I do is I call out showAlert(), but Alert (cheatProtection function) does not happen. What is wrong?

Thanks, Yan

Comment: You are calling init() somewhere in your calling class, right?

Comment: hmm.. I'm doing: 
rollOut="showAlert()"

something is missing?

Comment: Right, but are you explicly calling init() at some point? If not, your timer never gets created. (Unless init() is called automatically; it's been a while since I created a Flex object.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be:

```
private var cheat:Timer;

private function init():void {
    cheat = new Timer(2000, 1);
    cheat.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, cheatProtection);
    cheat.start();
}

private function showAlert():void {
    cheat.reset();
    cheat.start();
}
private function alrt_close(evt:CloseEvent):void {
    cheat.stop();
}

private function cheatProtection(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    Alert.show("Text", "Label", Alert.OK, this, alrt_close);
}
init();
```

Comment: Yes! :) how would then I be able to stop the timer? on the rollOver?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, if this helps, but in the Adobe Flex documentation the TimerEvent listener is added after start() is called.